# spring context is not loading beans from XML file

Tags: java, spring

We have an issue that we struggle to debug, so any help is appreciated.
We use spring `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`. In some cases the loader loads 49 beans and in other cases it loads only 1 bean without noticable difference in configuration. I am trying to find a way to get more debug information. This is the log I have right now:

```
62 2018-10-25T11:33:45.030Z DEBUG [main] [PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity():119] - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
     63 2018-10-25T11:33:45.056Z DEBUG [main] [DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions():92] - Loading bean definitions
     64 2018-10-25T11:33:45.058Z DEBUG [main] [XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions():224] - Loaded 1 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:ops-services.xml]
```

Is there anything else I should look for?

EDIT:

Here is my schema definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

I am using spring `4.3.20.RELEASE`

EDIT 2:
We found the cause. The file `ops-services.xml` was loaded twice. Once was the legit place, and once from a test jar that was loaded by mistake.

Is there a maven plugin, log messages or any other mean to make sure the same resource does not exist more than once in the classpath?

Comment: Check if `spring-beans` schema has correct version which match your spring dependencies version. Maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Can you add your source code or configuration that instantiates and uses the `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` or Spring context?

Comment: spring beans schema is http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd and I use spring 4. Is that an issue?

Comment: Do not specify version I think. Just `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"` ([see](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html)). But, if the beans are randomly loaded, you maybe have a conflict between configurations. Do you have more configuration files ?

Comment: Yes, it has import of other files